# SQL SPLIT function for subtraction?

Tags: sql, split, db2

I have table in DB2

```
id     HOURS     HOURSMINUTESECECONDS
1000   450.5     30:30:30
```

Hours is float value and HOURSMINUTESSECONDS is string value

I subtract them by using this function:

```
    (HOURS - 
(CAST(substr(HOURSMINUTESSECONDS , 1, 2) AS float) +
 CAST(substr(HOURSMINUTESECONDS , 4, 2) AS float)/60 + 
CAST(substr(HOURSMINUTESECONDS , 7, 2) AS float)/3600)) as diff
```

But if my row in HOURSMINUTESECONDS has value on example 300:30:30 or 3000:30:30 etc this won't work (ERROR) because substring will take only first elements.

So how this can be solved (SPLIT?) ? To take full value between ":" no meter how many charatcters?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- use [`LOCATE`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.doc.sqlref/flocate.htm) (that tells you index of an occurence of a substring in a string)
- or, reference the colons relative to the end of your string:

`(HOURS - 
(CAST(substr(HOURSMINUTESSECONDS , 1, LENGTH(HOURSMINUTESSECONDS) - 6) AS float) +
 CAST(substr(HOURSMINUTESECONDS , LENGTH(HOURSMINUTESSECONDS) - 4, 2) AS float)/60 + 
CAST(substr(HOURSMINUTESECONDS , LENGTH(HOURSMINUTESSECONDS) - 1, 2) AS float)/3600)) as diff`

Comment: it works. you just missed last -2; it should write -1. Thanks regards

Answer (score 0):

Can you use MOD function?

```
select 
    (hoursminutesseconds mod 10000) +
    ((hoursminutesseconds/100) mod 100)/60 +
    (hoursminutesseconds mod 100)*3600 
from
(
select replace(hoursminutesseconds,':','') as hoursminutesseconds from table
) as t
```

Comment: No I cant- it is string value